# No internet access on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8

I have a new laptop with Windows 8. When I try connect it to the internet all the Metro apps don't work, and in the tray (on network connection monitor) I see a yellow triangle with an exclamation sign inside (indicating No internet access). However all desktop apps work fine, and even updates of the operating system have been installed successfully.

My provider provides me direct access to internet, I mean I have not configured any VPN access. I get IP address from my provider's DHCP server.

Have you any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**

There is such a feature in windows 8 named [NCSI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) 
It might be found in registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`

There is a parameter `EnableActiveProbing`. On my windows the value of that parameter was set to zero by default. I tried to change it to 1, restarted my computer and enjoyed with normal access to internet and with working metro apps.

So now, microsoft will track all ip adresses I establish the connection from:)

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem I've been having for a few days now.  Good find.