# Permanently save registry changes

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

How can I permanently save changes made to registry in Windows 8. When I make some changes there and perform reboot all the changes made before gone. I'm setting `EnableActivePolling` to 1(because default value is 0) to provide my OS with normal internet access. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/639632/no-internet-access-on-windows-8/640123#640123) topic for details

Comment: If you are changing the key and it's being reverted the you have software installed to prevent the registry key from being changed this an office or personal computer?

Comment: if you are using company hardware do not mess with that. instead, ask your IT departments to fulfil your needs. you may be doing a contract breach and/or be held responsible for it.

Comment: it's my personal laptop and i want to be able to change registry's keys

Comment: As a way,You can export it to a file.reg using regedit. and then import it back. You can easily write scripts to load your registry files everytime it is logged in or save the registry files automatically when you shutdown.

Comment: yes, everything is possible, but there must be an easy way to do this. Why do you need such OS that doesn't allow you to do anything?